# DataNode after recovering from failure

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

After recovering from the failure does the DataNode has the data prior to failure or is there any change in the content of data in the DataNode?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this depends on how replication is setup. The default is 3, so even if data was missing from one node, the namenode will know that datanode is bad and go get a different copy

Answer (score 0):

All the data from the DN is deleted and the replication of the data residing in this DN is replicated to other datanodes in few seconds, when NN finds that this particular DN is dead..